# Why isn't memcpy in the import table?

Tags: c++, symbols, memcpy, pdb-files, dumpbin

I was playing with a pdb generated by Visual Studio when I saw `memcpy` in the list of symbols so I used dumpbin to inspect the import table in the executable but there was no reference to `memcpy` there.

Isn't `memcpy` a function exported from crt library?  If so, why don`t I see it in the output of dumpbin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memcpy` is often treated as an [intrinsic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43.aspxz), especially when copying small items, and thus is compiled entirely as inline code.

Try copying something larger.  Then you might see it in the import table.

Comment: this is really !! I tried with some mega bytes and it's now imported from VCRUNTIME140.dll , if you don't mind can I ask you : will memcpy always compiled as inline when I use /MT to build static executable as I noticed that when I use c++ std functions I get some winapi that they are wrappers for in the import table but not the situation with memcpy it doesn't depend on any winapi function

Comment: I doubt the compiler cares about that flag when it's deciding what code to emit for any particular invocation of `memcpy ()` since  (as I'm sure you know) all it does is control whether the program is linked statically or dynamically.  You can experiment further [here](https://godbolt.org) if you want to check it out yourself.  And you can accept my answer if you want to reward me for sharing - that's the usual practise here.  Thx.

Comment: @dev65 I don't think you have the rep yet to vote but you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). (I am _shameless_ :)